# Redirect user to mobile site and back in typo3 with typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have found that if I use the below typoscript I can redirect my users to the mobile version of the site which has its own tree in the backend of my typo3 site.

```
[useragent = *iPhone*]||[useragent = *iPod*]||[useragent = *Android*]
config.additionalHeaders = Location: http://m.example.com/
[end]
```

It is a simplified version of the site however so I want to have a return to full website link. But due to my above typoscript redirecting users to the m domain i can't get back to www.example.com.

Does anyone have any typoscript suggestions here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an additional parameter in your link back which you can use to turn off the redirection.

Try something like this:

```
# check for mobile browser
[useragent = *iPhone*]||[useragent = *iPod*]||[useragent = *Android*]
config.additionalHeaders = Location: http://m.example.com/
[global]

# undo mobile redirect if mobile param is set
[globalVar = GP:nomobileredirect > 0]
config.additionalHeaders =
[global]
```

and redirect to http://www.example.com/?nomobileredirect=1 on your link back.

To keep a nomobileredirect-value in all generated links, add nomobileredirect to your linkVars, e.g.

```
config.linkVars = nomobileredirect,L
```

Comment: Thanks that is a great help.  The only thing I am finding is after I get back to http://www.example.com/?nomobileredirect=1 and I click on say about us which is http://www.example.com/index.php?id=2 I lose the parameter and get taken back to m.example.com is there a way that you know of around this?

Comment: I edited my answer to include config.linkVars configuration. For more about how that works, here is the doc: http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.1.0/view/7/3/

Comment: Works well thanks. Another consideration I have which I haven't been able to work out is if you click on a link to a news article from twitter/facebook etc you get redirected to the home page which is not a great experience. Is there a way to have config.additionalHeaders = Location: http://m.example.com/index.php?id=(pid) or something similar so my news single page will redirect to the mobile version eg http://www.example.com/index.php?id=10&tx_ttnews[year]=2012

will go to

http://m.example.com/index.php?id=20&tx_ttnews[year]=2012

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way that I can see. You would need the ability to have variables in config.addtionalheaders, but currently, config.additionalheaders is just a string, so there's no way to add a variable. The relevant feature request is here: http://forge.typo3.org/issues/23494. If you want to do this, you would need to change from a typo3-based redirect mechanism to an htaccess-based redirect mechanism. How to do that should be easily google-able, but is out of scope for this question.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation you have been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another condition on a GET parameter and override the `config.additionalHeaders` later. Remember, TS is not a scripting language, but rather a static configuration. The last statement always wins and rendering starts only once all TS has been parsed.

You can also try to extend the above condition by an additional exclude of a GET parameter.